# Only use this element for ng-click in multiple elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use this html code render out several container elements. The `ng-repeat="card in cards"` element isn't actually rendered since there is no `$scope.cards`;

```
<div id="container" ng-controller='DemoController'>
  <div ng-repeat = "movie in movies" class="repeat">

    <a ng-click="addMovie()" ui-sref=".container-big" >More info</a>
    <div ng-repeat="card in cards" my-card="card"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

If a user clicks on the `a` it fires the `addMovie()` function,

```
$scope.addMovie = function() {
    $scope.cards.push(new Card());
};
```

This in return creates a new card, since there is now a card the `<div ng-repeat="card in cards" my-card="card"></div>` gets created in the `.repeat` element.

The above element has a directive called `my-card="card"`. So when the element is created it also fire the directive

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myCard', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div ui-view="container-big"></div>',
        replace: true,
        transclude: false
    };
});
```

which replaces this element

```
<div ng-repeat="card in cards" my-card="card"></div>
```

with this element

```
<div ui-view="container-big"></div>
```

The `a` also has a `ui-sref=".container-big"` which injects a template into the newly created `<div ui-view="container-big"></div>`.

See it in action here > http://plnkr.co/edit/B7CRjvdQ9paytwl5csKi?p=preview

My question is, can I restrict the click action of

```
 <a ng-click="addMovie()" ui-sref=".container-big" >More info</a>
```

To only the clicked element. So instead of of firing all the `addMovie()` functions on all elements. I only fire it on the clicked element resulting in only one container changing.

Comment: `$scope.addMovie` or you are referring to `$scope.addCard` ?

Comment: Sorry, small error while editiing the post. `$scope.addCard` doesn't exist and I am refering to `$scope.addMovie`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a separate cards array for each movie. One way to do this is to make `cards` a property of `movie`.

In the HTML, we modify it to pass `movie` to `addCard()`. In this context, `movie` is the current movie that the `ng-repeat` is iterating over. Without this, the `addCard()` function would not be aware of what movie it should be adding cards to. We also change the second `ng-repeat` to use `movie.cards` so that it knows to only look at the cards pertaining to that movie.

```
<div ng-repeat = "movie in movies" class="repeat">
  <a ng-click="addCard(movie)" ui-sref=".container-big" >More info</a>
  <div ng-repeat="card in movie.cards" my-card="card"></div>
</div>
```

In the JavaScript, we modify the `addCard()` function so that it takes `movie` as an argument. We also need to change it so that it creates a place to store the cards for that movie

```
$scope.addCard = function(movie) {
    // create movie.cards array if it does not exist
    if (!movie.cards) {
      movie.cards = [];
    }
    // add the card to the list of cards for this movie
    movie.cards.push(new Card());
};
```

Comment: Looks like it's working, thank you for that. Could you explain the logic behind the code a little bit more? What value is being passed with the `movie` in the `addCard(movie)`? What is the `movie.cards` code in the JS? An array? What are the || for? Hope you can explain my questings a bit.